# Wire colors in Targus laptop charger

Tags: laptop-repair, charger

I have a charger that came with my laptop, which is broken and a *Targus APA69 Univeral charger*, which is missing the plug.

As I am traveling and short on cash, I decided to attempt to splice the plug from the broken charger with the cable of the Targus charger. Once I cut open the Targus' cable, I found an number of different wires, and have no real idea which is which.

The (six) wires from the Targus charger are:

- Red
- White
- Yellow
- Blue
- Green
- One bare/unsheathed wire

The plug only has two wires, one red and one white.

How can I determine which cables should be connected to (safely) charge my laptop?

Answer (score 2):

Since the Targus charger can charge multiple devices (even at once) just by changing the tip, I think that those wires all carry different voltages. I haven't been able to find the color coding of those wires, so I think your only solution is to use a voltage measuring device (or a multimeter) to check all those pairs of cables for the right two that give out the needed voltage for your laptop. I am 90% sure the free/unsheathed wire is the negative/ground wire, so you can start from there.

You need to be careful since playing around with this can fry your laptop. You might be short on cash now, but you'll be a lot shorter if you damage your laptop. If I were you I would just get a new charger.